# issue with @font-face on mozilla while using Shopify

Tags: css, font-face, shopify

I am using the css

```
 @font-face {
 font-family: ChangaOne-Regular;
 src: url({{ 'changaone-regular.eot' | asset_url }});
 src: url({{ 'changaone-regular.eot?#iefix' | asset_url }}) format('embedded-opentype'),  url({{ 'changaone-regular.woff' | asset_url }}) format('woff'),  url({{ 'changaone-regular.ttf' | asset_url }}) format('truetype'),  url({{'changaone-regular.svg#changaone-regular' | asset_url }}) format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

I have saved the font in images folder. Since it was not taking the font I created the copy of the font in the folder within my css file.

Now it is working perfectly on chrome. But in mozilla the font is not getting read. 
I found that we can fix this by adding htaccess to the folder of the css file with content

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

This is also not making any difference in firefox. So how can we fix this? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an absolute URL to the font file.

Comment: Does firefox debug log show anything? (Press ctrl+shift+k and then refresh page)

Comment: [08:54:12.459] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "ChangaOne-Regular" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: http://assets0.zipzoomautodealer.com/alpha/files/1959/1957/assets/changaone-regular.woff

Comment: I have fixed this issue by adding google font using @import. Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Cool stuff, anytime! I've had a few FF web font issues and they always seem to be URL related!

Comment: Yes this was also url related. I was using this on a shopify website, and there we are using the complete url for font. Also the domain name of the font will not be the domain name of our site. so I had to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Still it was not working.