# @font-face not displaying correctly in site

Tags: css, font-face, shopify

I have a myshopify site that I am trying to display a font in using `@font-face`.. but for some reason, the font is not taking effect.. here is what I have:

font files in asset folder

using myshopify asset url in css:

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    src: url('{{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.eot' | asset_url }}');
    src: url('{{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.eot?iefix' | asset_url }}') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url({{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.woff' | asset_url }}) format('woff'),
    url('{{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.ttf' | asset_url }}') format('truetype'),
    url('{{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.svg#LeagueGothicRegular' | asset_url }}') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


..

#top-menu a{
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular', sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.97em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 18px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

anything pop out?
THANKYOU!

Answer (score 0):

I found a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519613/issue-with-font-face-on-mozilla-while-using-shopify) regarding using font-faces with Shopify which seems to indicate that you need to *remove* the outer quotes from wherever you are using the `asset_url` filter within a css url (this is the opposite of what I suggested in my original answer):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LeagueGothicRegular';
    src: url({{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.eot' | asset_url }});
    src: url({{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.eot?iefix' | asset_url }}) format('embedded-opentype'),
         url({{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.woff' | asset_url }}) format('woff'),
         url({{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.ttf' | asset_url }}) format('truetype'),
         url({{ 'League_Gothic-webfont.svg#LeagueGothicRegular' | asset_url }}) format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This seems to be confirmed by the `asset_url` [documentation page](http://wiki.shopify.com/Asset_url) (near the bottom).

According to the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519613/issue-with-font-face-on-mozilla-while-using-shopify), you may also need to modify the htaccess for the folder containing the fonts.

Comment: Is your CSS file saved with a .liquid extension?  According to [this](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/css-disregards-liquid-tags-115513), that may be needed in order for Shipify to know to parse the file.

Comment: Since my original answer was off the mark, I updated it with some new info that I found.  Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

Upon further inspection my font files had different permissions than they rest of my theme files. I used chmod to make them 644 like the others, and then re-uploaded. Worked like a charm.

`chmod 644 LeagueGoth*`

And re-upload.